# compact hover function

Tags: jquery

I have bunch of hover functions which do the same

```
$('#101').mouseover(function () {
        $('#p1_101').stop().animate({"fill-opacity": 1}, 200);
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $('#p1_101').stop().animate({"fill-opacity": .7}, 200);
});
$('#102').mouseover(function () {
        $('#p1_102').stop().animate({"fill-opacity": 1}, 200);
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $('#p1_102').stop().animate({"fill-opacity": .7}, 200);
});
$('#103').mouseover(function () {
        $('#p1_103').stop().animate({"fill-opacity": 1}, 200);
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $('#p1_103').stop().animate({"fill-opacity": .7}, 200);
});
```

how to write this in one function ??

html

thwre is a table with , , ....

and svg paths which have , ,  and every one is different, it is impossible to show it here

Comment: all of the selector is 'id', why dont use 'class'?

Comment: your id value is invalid, [id should start with a alphabet](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)

Comment: @ArunPJohny - html5 allows ids that start with (or are made up entirely of) digits. The link you provided is to an html4 spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.each([1, 2, 3], function (index, value) {
    $('#10' + value).hover(
    function () {
        $('#p1_10' + value).stop().animate({"fill-opacity": 1}, 200);
    },
    function () {
        $('#p1_10' + value).stop().animate({"fill-opacity": .7}, 200);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
$.each(['01', '02', '03'], function (index, value) {
    $('#1' + value).hover(
    function () {
        $('#p1_1' + value).stop().animate({"fill-opacity": 1}, 200);
    },
    function () {
        $('#p1_1' + value).stop().animate({"fill-opacity": .7}, 200);
    });
});
```

Comment: but what if i have more than 10 id's ? i add 0 to each function 01, 02, 03 and cut off 0 from id of hover but it dosent work, whhy ?

Comment: i just did it, like i said  i add 0 to each function 01, 02, 03 and cut off 0 from id of hover but it dosent work

Comment: yep :] this is it, do u know why is that ??

Comment: I think `1, 2, 3` were integer, so when you changed it to `01, 02, 03`, the resulted values were still `1`, `2`, `3`. So it didn't work.
Now we converted that into string `'01','02','03'` and that's works. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about like this:

```
  function myFunction(var str){
    $('#'+str).mouseover(function () {
      $('#p1_'+str).stop().animate({"fill-opacity": 1}, 200);
    }).mouseout(function () {
      $('#p1_'+str).stop().animate({"fill-opacity": .7}, 200);
    });
  }

  myFunction('101');
  myFunction('102');
  myFunction('103');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll be making some tweaks to the markup and javascript

HTML (a sample based on the given case)

```
<div class="my-el" pel="#p1_101">101</div>
<p id="p1_101">p1</p>

<div class="my-el" pel="#p1_102">102</div>
<p id="p1_102">p2</p>

<div class="my-el" pel="#p1_103">103</div>
<p id="p1_103">p3</p>

<div class="my-el" pel="#p1_104">104</div>
<p id="p1_104">p4</p>
```

Script

```
$(function(){
    $('.my-el').mouseover(function () {
        $($(this).attr('pel')).stop().animate({"fill-opacity": 1}, 200);
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $($(this).attr('pel')).stop().animate({"fill-opacity": .7}, 200);
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t697L/)

Answer (score 0):

If, as in the code you show, the element to be animated always has an id that is `"p1_"` plus the id of the element being hovered, then you can bind the same functions to all of the elements and then just get the id of the currently hovered element by using `this.id` within the functions:

```
$('#101,#102,#103').mouseover(function () {
        $('#p1_' + this.id).stop().animate({"fill-opacity": 1}, 200);
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $('#p1_' + this.id).stop().animate({"fill-opacity": .7}, 200);
});
```